# Importing homemade module to bokeh --serve myapp.py

Tags: bokeh

I'm trying to run a own version of the "Crossfilter" example shown in bokeh/examples. The data I'm visulizing is handled in a homemade module and when I import that in my bokeh script and run in via Spyder it doesnt raise any error but via the terminal it says ImportError: "No module named ****"

Do I need to do something else to apply this module so that bokeh can find it?

Thanks
(My bokeh version is:0.12.16

Answer (score 0):

I think I know why my script is not working, I've got bokeh installed in two places on my computer and in cmd it looks at the "wrong" installation and that one doesnt have my module installed.